# Highlight the row based on what a cell total is?

Tags: excel

Can you highlight a row based on what a cell has in it.  Specifically I want to put #'s in lets say A3-A15, have A16 give me the total for the cells.  If the total is between 18000 and 19999 I want the row to highlight yellow if the quantity in cell A16 is more than 20000 I want the row to highlight red.

Comment: Crystal: Welcome to SO, but please take a look at the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq I want... (gimme teh codez) does not go over well. Please put in some effort on the problem before posting a question. (What have you tried? comments to follow...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of the `SUM` formula and conditional formatting to achieve that.

In cell A16, you can put `=SUM(A3:A15)`

From there, you can select cell A16, and (depending on your version) go to Format > Conditional Formatting, and enter the following formulas:

- Cell Value Is - Between - 18000 - 19999 -> Format -> Patterns -> Yellow
- Cell Value Is - Greater Than Or Equal To - 20000 -> Format -> Patterns -> Red

Comment: Yes I have that but can I make the entire row be the yellow or red like cell A16?

Comment: you can conditionally format each cell in the row based on the value in a particular cell. Just apply the format across the row, or the cells in the row you want formatted. Assuming you have XL2007/2010

Comment: Sorry, can you be a little more specific?  I would have to format each cell?

Comment: yes @CrystalAdkins, you apply the conditional formatting to each cell, but the condition is on the cell with `=SUM(A3:A15)` cell A16 in your example.